# Replacing @import with @use and @forward causing "This module was already loaded, so it can't be configured using 'with'" error

Tags: css, import, sass

**TL;DR:**

I have problems migrating from "@import" to "@use" and "@forward". Components that inherit a parent give that error.

**LONG:**

I have a library that is a collection of components with similar rules. Some components are just extensions of other components, so they "inherit" the same code and variables of their parents and build another, separated, component.

Let's you an example.
I have a basic component SimpleButton and 2 components that extends this basic component. They are called ComplexButton and AdvancedButton.
These 3 components can be used as completely different entities and can be included together on the same page.

I "import" these files:

```
@use "components/atoms/buttons/AdvancedButton.scss";
@use "components/atoms/buttons/ExpertButton.scss" with (
       $color: red,
);
```

Both AdvancedButton and ExpertButton have "@use SimpleButton.scss as inherited" and "@forward SimpleButton.scss", because I many variables are only within SimpleButton but they are widely used on the other 2.

They both @use and @forward SimpleButton.scss (because it has all the $variables needed and that we can change with @use with)
I get this error:

> "This module was already loaded, so it can't be configured using "with").

Reading the documentation, it is said that "@use with" is "one time only" and "project wide". But I thought that namespacing and modules would have been less strict and more reusable.

With @import, now deprecated, I could do everything without problems. Now I'm going crazy because I don't see a solution to this problem.

If you are wondering, this is the library that I am working on (vitepress is needed to read the md files):
https://github.com/Guebbit/scss-library/
It's an open source and free as in freedom library that I want to use on various volunteering projects (united with other similar libraries)

Thank you for your time and patience. I will unconditionally love who will solve this problem for me. Giving me a solution or a tip or a best practice that could be used in this case.
You are my last hope.

Comment: The reason you can only configure each module once is because each variable in a module can only have a single value during the compilation. The same thing is true for `@import`—each variable only has a single value at a time—it's just less obvious when you're overwriting them.

It may be simpler not to use `with` at all and to just set variables manually after you load a library. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, buy why this happens even in a namespaced "safe" enviroment? What's the point of this new system if there is the imperative "don't replace a value with another"?

@import was chaotic, but this is extremely strict without reason. Placing an hard stop on something that one could have wanted to use.

But I can't believe there is no way around, I can't believe they just removed this feature and to hell with everyone that was using it, that's why I'm searching for a solution... it has to be there :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "even in a namespaced 'safe' environment". The underlying logic here is the same as with `@import`: each variable has only a single value at any time. You can overwrite those variables at any time by writing `namespace.$variable: value`. The `with` clause _specifically_ means "load this with these overrides" and that only works once because you can only load a module once. I don't understand the confusion.

Comment: I thought it was something like a scope in javascript. It's not the same as @import because with it you can do many things that works instead of having an blocking error that won't let you go further :(

Comment: At the moment I reverted and started using `@import` again. I don't see a way to use `@use` and `@forward` as a replacement for `@import` and neither do other people it seems. It's a shame, I really hoped for a better implementation of the DRY concept but it seems we'll have to keep waiting.

Comment: Sass isn't JavaScript, and expecting it to work the same way won't usually guide you in the right direction. If you're struggling with errors when using `@use`, that likely means that the `@import` equivalent was already doing something wrong, it just wasn't telling you about it. Posting a small reproduction case that's not behaving how you expect would make it a lot easier to help you debug the issue.